# in selenium how to use string variable into xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

How to pass variable inside my xpath and use it? Or please advise if there is a better way to do this.
Then I will do IF condition, in case my page will contents appropriate report name.

[image]

```
here is a pseudo code: 
unique_report_name = ("rep" + str(randint(100, 200)))
create report...
search created report...
result = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Report Name :"unique_report_name"')]")  
  if result is displayed: 
    do something...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the HTML you posted, I don't see any quotation marks in `Report Name : rep101` so these quotation marks may not be necessary. Based on the HTML, here's how I would write the XPath:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h1[contains(text(), 'Report Name : " + unique_report_name + "')]")
```

However, if `rep101` is actually surrounded by qutoation marks, you will need to use escape characters in Python to do this. Here's how I would refactor your XPath, if there are quotation marks in the text:

```
result = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Report Name :\"unique_report_name\"')]")
```

The `\` character will escape your `"` characters in the XPath, so your string will not be interrupted.